# iOS : When saving photos to the folder memory overflow

Tags: ios, memory, overflow

I use instruments to detect my program, the following code detects memory leaks。
  Looking forward to your help, thank you!

int count=(int)array.count;

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) { 
    set=(ALAsset *)[array objectAtIndex:i];

    CGImageRef ref1= [set thumbnail];

    CGImageRef ref=[[set defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage];

    NSData * imagedata2=[[NSData alloc]init];

    imagedata2=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ref],1);

   // CGImageRelease(ref);

    NSString * photoNmaeOgiginal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_origianl.jpg",uuid];

    NSString *PhtotoOriginalPath=[AlbumFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoNmaeOgiginal ];          

 BOOL      resultOriginal=  [NSData writeToFile:PhtotoOriginalPath atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one obvious issue with the code you posted, the line `NSData * imagedata2=[[NSData alloc]init];` is totally not need since the next line just replaces the object.
Which would trigger memory leak

So replace:

```
NSData * imagedata2=[[NSData alloc]init];

imagedata2=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ref],1);
```

With

```
NSDate *imagedata2=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ref],1);
```